# Why is $\beta^{T}X_{c}^{T}X_{c}\beta$ divided by $(k-1)\sigma^{2}$ in multiple regression?

Tags: regression, linear, matrix

In single linear regression mmodel, to find expectation of regression, we use the following formula:
$$E[MSR] = \sigma^{2}+\hat \beta^{2}(X-\bar X)^{2}.$$

$MSR = \frac{\sum_{i=0}^n (\hat y-\bar y)^{2}}{\operatorname{df}}$;
$\operatorname{df}= 1.$

When it comes to a multiple regression model, the formula is

$$E[MSR] = \sigma^{2}+\frac{\beta^{T}X_{c}^{T}X_{c}\beta}{(k-1)\times\sigma^{2}}.$$

Can anyone explain why we have to divide $\beta^{T}X_{c}^{T}X_{c}\beta$ by $(k-1)\sigma^{2}$?

Comment: There are typographical errors in your notes.  There *must* be because the units of $\sigma^2$ are the squares of the response units, whereas the remaining stuff in the red box is unitless.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Questioned reformed and hope it is clearer more now.

Comment: What does "$X_c$" refer to??

Comment: It refers to (X-X_bar)

Answer (score 3):

**It is useful to use the units calculus as a quick check of formulas.**  The formulas in the question illustrate this.

Suppose the response $Y$ is measured in units $[U]$ such as grams, centimeters, seconds, or whatever.  Thus the residuals $y-\hat y$ are also in units of $[U].$  Furthermore, because $\sigma^2$ is the variance of $Y,$ its units are $[U^2].$  When any explanatory variable $X_i$ is measured in units $[V],$ its product with the coefficient $\beta_i$ must be in the same units as $Y.$  Therefore the units of $\beta_i$ must be $[U]/[V].$

Use these (elementary, simple) observations to check the units on both sides of an equation.  The first one for MSR reads

$$E[MSR] [U^2] = \sigma^2 [U^2] + (\hat\beta [U]/[V])^2 (X_c [V])^2$$

and the units on both sides work out to

$$[U^2] = [U^2] + \frac{[U^2]}{[V^2]} [V^2] = [U^2].$$

This doesn't prove the formula is correct, but it does show it is consistent: the two sides are *commensurable.*

In the second formula, we have seen the numerator of the fraction is in units of $[U^2],$ whence

$$E[MSR][U^2]\ \overset{?}=\ \sigma^{2}[U^2] +\frac{\beta^\prime X_{c}^\prime X_{c}\beta [U^2]}{(k-1)\times\sigma^{2} [U^2]}.$$

The first term on the right hand side is in units of $[U^2],$ matching those on the left, *but the second term is in units of $[U^2]/[U^2] = 1,$ which is incommensurable with $[U^2].$*  This *proves* the formula is incorrect.

The correct formula does not have "$\sigma^2$" in the denominator on the right hand side (as you might guess, because this is the simplest way of modifying the formula to make the units match).  See Montgomery *at al.* Introduction to Linear Regression Analysis (Fifth Edition) appendix C.3 for details.

For completeness, here's a version of the correct formula in terms of the sum of squares of the regression:

$$E[SSR] = (k-1)\sigma^2 + \beta^\prime X^\prime_C X_C\beta$$

$SSR/\sigma^2$ follows a *noncentral* $\chi^2$ distribution.  Its degrees of freedom is the rank of ${X_C}^\prime X_C$ (the effective number of variables, not counting the intercept, indicated by "$k-1$" in this formula because it's usually one less than the number of columns $k$ of $X$) and $\beta^\prime X^\prime_C X_C\beta/\sigma^2$ (which we have seen is unitless) is its noncentrality parameter, *id.*

Answer (score 1):

In what follows I will expand on [whuber's answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/624633/136579) and derive the correct expression for the expected value of the regression mean square $MSR = \sum_{i=1}^n \left(\hat{y}_i - \bar{y}\right)^2 / \left(k - 1 \right).$

---

Let $P_X$ denote the [orthogonal projector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_matrix#Ordinary_least_squares) onto the column space of the [design matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_matrix) $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}$ , i.e. $P_X = X\left(X^\top X\right)^{-1}X^\top$, and let $C_n$ denote the [centering matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centering_matrix) of order $n$, i.e., $C_n = I_n - \frac{1}{n} \mathbf{1}_n \mathbf{1}_n^\top$.

Using these matrices, and $\bar{\hat{y}} = \bar{y}$,<sup>1</sup> we can rewrite the regression sum of squares as
$
\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\hat{y}_i- \bar{y}\right)^2 = \left(C_n \hat{y}\right)^\top\left(C_n \hat{y}\right) = \left(C_n P_X y\right)^\top\left(C_n P_X y\right) = y^\top P_X^\top C_n^\top C_n P_X y.
$
Now, since $\mathbf{1}_n$ is in the column space of $X$,<sup>1</sup> we have $P_X \mathbf{1}_n = \mathbf{1}_n$. Together with the symmetry and idempotency of $P_X$ this yields that $C_n P_X = P_X - \frac{1}{n} \mathbf{1}_n \mathbf{1}_n^\top$ is symmetric and idempotent; hence $\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\hat{y}_i- \bar{y}\right)^2 = y^\top C_n P_X y$.

Since $y \sim \mathop{\mathcal N}\left(X\beta, \sigma^2 I_n\right)$ and $\mathop{\mathrm{tr}}\left(C_n P_X\right) = \mathop{\mathrm{tr}}\left(X^\top X\left(X^\top X\right)^{-1} \right) - \frac{1}{n}\mathop{\mathrm{tr}}\left(\mathbf{1}_n \mathbf{1}_n^\top\right) = k -1$, we get (compare, e.g., with the derivation [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/606643))
$$
\frac{1}{\sigma^2} \sum_{i=1}^n \left(\hat{y}_i - \bar{y}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{\sigma^2} y^\top C_n P_X y \sim \mathop{\chi_{k-1}^2}\left(\lambda\right),
$$
where $\lambda = \frac{1}{\sigma^2} \beta^\top X^\top C_n P_X X \beta = \frac{1}{\sigma^2} \beta^\top X^\top C_n X \beta$ denotes the non-centrality parameter of the non-central chi-squared distribution with $k−1$ degrees of freedom.
Symmetry and idempotency of $C_n$ give $\lambda = \frac{1}{\sigma^2} \beta^\top X^\top C_n^\top C_n X \beta$, which (with the centering property of $C_n$) yields $\lambda = \frac{1}{\sigma^2} \beta^\top X_c^\top X_c \beta$.

Finally, $\mathop{\mathbb{E}}\left[\mathop{\chi_{k-1}^2}\left(\lambda\right)\right] = \left(k - 1\right) + \lambda = \left(k - 1\right) + \frac{1}{\sigma^2} \beta^\top X_c^\top X_c \beta$, and therefore $\mathop{\mathbb{E}}\left[MSR\right] = \mathop{\mathbb{E}}\left[\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\hat{y}_i - \bar{y}\right)^2 / \left(k - 1 \right)\right] = \sigma^2 + \frac{1}{k - 1} \beta^\top X_c^\top X_c \beta.$

---

<sup>1</sup>The derivation relies on the fact that the linear regression model contains an intercept.